# React/Express: POST error 413: Payload too large (Bodyparser does not work)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, body-parser

I've tried everything but this just seems impossible to fix. I have browsed [every](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967138/node-js-express-js-bodyparser-post-limit) [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332561/node-js-express-large-body-for-bodyparser) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large) on stackoverflow and burned through 3 google pages.

**Things I've tried**

1. Added `extended: true/false` within bodyParser.json
2. Used bodyParser.urlencoder()
3. Switched over and used multer extension following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srPXMt1Q0nY) but kept getting a `path not found` error.

Someone please help

React handlePrinting function:

```
async function handlePrinting (file) {
    const raw = file.getFileEncodeBase64String()
    const destination = 'printer'
    const key = file.file.lastModified
    var data = {
      raw: raw,
      pageRanges: pageRanges,
      sides: sides,
      copies: copies,
      destination: destination,
      key: key
    }

    await axios
      .post('/api/print/submit', data)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

Express:

```
router.use(bodyParser.json({
  parameterLimit: 100000,
  limit: '50mb'
}))

router.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  const data = {
    raw: req.body.raw,
    pageRanges: req.body.pageRanges,
    sides: req.body.sides,
    copies: req.body.copies,
    destination: req.body.destination,
    key: req.body.key,
  }

  Print.create(data, (error, post) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`Printing submit error: ${error}`)
      return res.sendStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
    }

    printFunction(data.raw, data.copies, data.sides, data.pageRanges, data.destination)
    return res.status(OK).send(post)
  })
})
```

Comment: I wonder if because you are setting the parser at Router level, the application limit is overriding the Router. Could you try applying the same setting at app level?

Comment: which node.js version do you use? try with latest node.js version.

Comment: I use node 13.5.0

Comment: Changing the limit on the application limit did not work. After some digging in the node-modules, I found out that if I manually change the value of options.limit from 100kb to 50mb, it worked. So the problem was that I wasn't actually calling the bodyParser.json function in my router.use.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this will help, have you tried using compression?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression

easy to use

import

```
const compression = require('compression');
```

use

```
app.use(compression());
```

another approach is do not use body parser, I don't usually.

```
app.use(express.json());
```

then to send

```
return res.status(200).json({data:data});
```