# NodeJS CORS error when req is too heavy (Files upload)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, cors

I'm working with an Angular front and a NodeJS API that actually run in prod with some aws services (S3 and Elastic Beanstalk).

I actually get this CORS error when I'm uploading an image that seems to be to heavy or when I upload more thant two images, each taking 200Ko.

[image: CORS error]

Of course, I have already set my headers and I shouldn't have any issue with CORS, the issue there is about some req size limitation.
There is some parts of my app.js.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/images", express.static(path.join("images")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    next();
});
```

THX !

Comment: Try this. `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    parameterLimit: 100000,
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true
  }));`. from here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967138/node-js-express-js-bodyparser-post-limit

Comment: I tried with this piece of code tho and I do have the same error. Fun fact, I don't have the error 'Error: request entity too large'

Answer (score 12):

When using a webserver like Nginx before Node, all requests go through Nginx and are validated by nginx before even reaching Node.js.

Nginx has a configuration file by default located in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. This file has a lot of default properties for all requests and one of these is `client_max_body_size`. The default value for that property is 1M (1 MB), and your file is most probably crossing this limit.

Check the logs of nginx just to be sure at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. You should see the following error `client intended to send too large body` present.

Inorder to fix this, simply put the following in your `nginx.conf`:
`client_max_body_size 10M;`. You can change the limit to whatever suits you.

Comment: To add on to the answer, add client_max_body_size 10M inside http { } in nginx.conf